# How to rewrite a Promise in Node / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

In another question - see [1] below - I asked how to iterate over a list and call an async function for each element in that list and finally use the accumulated result list.

User tresdin [2] was so kind to point to Promises in Node.

His example is exactly what I was looking for. Here it is again:

```
var request = require("request"),
    cheerio = require("cheerio"),
    base_url = "http://de.indeed.com/Jobs?q=";  // after equal sign for instance:   sinatra&l=
var Promise = require('promise');

var search_words = ["django", "python", "flask", 
                    "rails", "ruby",
                    "node", "javascript", "angularjs", "react",
                    "java", "grails", "groovy",
                    "php", "symfony", "laravel" ];


Promise.all(
    search_words.map( function(keyword) {  // map function on each element in search_words
        return new Promise( function(resolve, reject) {   // create a Promise instance for each element in search_words
            request( base_url + keyword + "&l=", function(err, resp, body) {
                if (err) {
                    return reject(err);
                }
                $ = cheerio.load(body);
                num = $("#searchCount")[0].children[0].data.split(" ").reverse()[0]; 
                resolve( [keyword, num] ); // will return value [keyword, num]
            }); // request( ... 
        }); // return new Promise(...)
    })  // map
) // Promise.all 
    .then( function(map_searchword) {
        console.log(map_searchword);
    }); // then
```

Calling it will deliver:

```
$ node promises_example.js
[ [ 'django', '139' ],
  [ 'python', '3.328' ],
  [ 'flask', '14' ],
  [ 'rails', '406' ],
  [ 'ruby', '1.061' ],
  [ 'node', '685' ],
  [ 'javascript', '9.169' ],
  [ 'angularjs', '1.164' ],
  [ 'react', '376' ],
  [ 'java', '19.100' ],
  [ 'grails', '47' ],
  [ 'groovy', '163' ],
  [ 'php', '4.978' ],
  [ 'symfony', '482' ],
  [ 'laravel', '110' ] ]
```

Now my question is: Can I move the "return new Promise" part outside of the iteration into a new function like so?

```
var request = require("request"),
    cheerio = require("cheerio"),
    base_url = "http://de.indeed.com/Jobs?q=";  // after equal sign for instance:   sinatra&l=
var Promise = require('promise');

var search_words = ["django", "python", "flask", 
                    "rails", "ruby",
                    "node", "javascript", "angularjs", "react",
                    "java", "grails", "groovy",
                    "php", "symfony", "laravel" ];


// moved "return new Promise()" out of iteration to a function
var do_request = function(keyword) {
    return new Promise( function(resolve, reject) {   // create a Promise instance for each element in search_words
        request( base_url + keyword + "&l=", function(err, resp, body) {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }
            $ = cheerio.load(body);
            num = $("#searchCount")[0].children[0].data.split(" ").reverse()[0]; 
            resolve( [keyword, num] ); // will return value [keyword, num]
        }); // request( ... 
    }); // return new Promise(...)
} // function

Promise.all(
    search_words.map( function(keyword) {  // map function on each element in search_words
        do_request(keyword);
    })  // map
) // Promise.all 
    .then( function(map_of_resolved_promises) {
        console.log(map_of_resolved_promises);
    }); // then
```

This will deliver a totally different result:

```
$ node promises_example_2.js
[ undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined ]
```

Can somebody explain as to why this is undefined?

---

[1] [Iterate over async function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36406314/iterate-over-async-function)

[2] https://stackoverflow.com/users/3247703/tresdin

Comment: Have you tried `search_words.map(do_request)`?

Comment: Excellent! This works! - But why?

Comment: you forgot to return do_request in the map function; this would work as well: `return do_request(keyword);`

Comment: Awesome! @kazenorin, that was the hint I needed! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to add a `return` statement :

```
Promise.all(
    search_words.map( function(keyword) {  // map function on each element in search_words
        return do_request(keyword);
    })
)
```

Or you can simply do:

```
Promise.all(search_words.map(do_request))
```

The `map` function will pass the its argument (here your keywords) directly to the `do_request` method.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! // Awesome to see how JavaScript reminds me of the Scheme programming language

Comment: I'm not really familiar with Scheme but I'm glad you are enjoying Javascript ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace

```
search_words.map( function(keyword) { 
    do_request(keyword);
})
```

with

```
search_words.map(do_request)
```

or

```
search_words.map( function(keyword) { 
    return do_request(keyword);
})
```

In th first example, the Promise returned from `do_request` is not being passed to `search_words.map` callback. As the result, `undefined` is returned instead. That's why you've got an array of `undefined` values.

The second example is an equivalent of the original code while the last one need an extra callback in each iteration. And thus, it require more memory. This means you should use the last solution only when some other stuffs need to be executed within the loop. For example:

```
search_words.map( function(keyword) { 
    return do_request(keyword + 'something');
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Would have accepted this answer (as it is a very good explanation), but user @cl3m was quicker. Thanks!